# Website redirect based query with cookie

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I have a website that used to be only a news page, but as we grown, I had to move the news section from homepage to domainname.com/news

To not confuse our loyal users when they landing on the new home page, I would like to give them an option (light box). The first time when you arrive to the homepage, you get a message, if you want to go directly to News and keep it as a default (or cancel). If you choose yes, next time you type our domain name, it will take you to the news section.

I hope there is a javascript that could do this job.

Comment: There is... you just haven't written it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to do an alert confirm() to find out what the user wants to do. From that set a cookie.

Next load, have PHP check the cookie to find out where to head to.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkCookie()
{
var wellcome=getCookie("firstime");
  if (wellcome!==null && wellcome!=="")
  {
     alert("Welcome");
  }
  else 
  {
    alert("is your first time");
    setCookie("firstime",true,365);
  }
}
```